# Eliminate border around SendBox of the ACS UI Library

Tags: acs

I need to be able to get rid of the border around SendBox in the ACS UI Library but I can't get access to that style. No matter what I tried, I could not get rid of that 1-pixel black boarder. I looked through all the styles in SendBoxStylesProps and none controlled that 1-pixle black box around the control. Using the F12 tools in the browser, I was able to find the style that contains the boarder, and I was able to toggle it off but it's a generated style so not sure how I can change the style in code.

I'd like to control more of the look and feel. I don't want a border around the SandBox at all which will allow me to set the entire SendBox to one solid color with rounded corners. It's so ugly when you change the corner radius of a div that has a border because the corners break and look strange.